# Nested React Native Flatlist styling

Tags: react-native-flatlist

I'm using nested flatlist in my app. In first flatlist there are array of titles and in second flatlist there are array of items. Now, I'm trying to display the first flatlist title to be visible until all the items of the second flatlist get scrolled. For eg.

first flatlist item ['nuts', 'cashews', 'drynuts', etc];
second flatlist items [[{}, {}, {}, {}, {}], [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}], [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}]]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I would suggest you using `SectionList`: https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist

Previously formatted your data

Comment: @James Matthew, you definetely should go with this suggestion. `Don't reinvent the wheel.` There is already a solution, that fits to your exact approach.